# I can't run dotnet ef on linux mint

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core

My setup:

-- Linux --
Distributor ID: Linuxmint
Description:    Linux Mint 21
Release:        21
Codename:       vanessa

-- Dotnet SDK--
6.0.402 [/home/gilmar/.dotnet/sdk]

-- Dotnet Runtime --
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.10 [/home/gilmar/.dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.10 [/home/gilmar/.dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

-- Dotnet Tools --

```
ID do Pacote      Versão      Comandos 
---------------------------------------
dotnet-ef         6.0.10      dotnet-ef
```

I have trouble when I try to run the command dotnet ef. When I do it, returns the message below:

```
You must install .NET to run this application.

App: /home/gilmar/.dotnet/tools/dotnet-ef
Architecture: x64
App host version: 6.0.10
.NET location: Not found

Learn about runtime installation:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/app-launch-failed

Download the .NET runtime:
https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?missing_runtime=true&arch=x64&rid=linuxmint.21-x64&apphost_version=6.0.10
```

I modified my file .bashrc adding the lines below:

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.dotnet"
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.dotnet/tools/"
```

The folders in my directory:

```
gilmar@hp ~ $ whereis dotnet
dotnet: /home/gilmar/.dotnet/dotnet

gilmar@hp ~ $ whereis dotnet-ef
dotnet-ef: /home/gilmar/.dotnet/tools/dotnet-ef
```

I can run normally dotnet restore, dotnet new, dotnet build, etc, but I can't run dotnet ef

I tried:

```
dotnet ef
dotnet-ef
dotnet dotnet-ef
dotnet dotnet ef
```

I installed dotnet using the script from Microsoft at https://dot.net/v1/dotnet-install.sh

Anyone can help me?
Thanks.

Comment: have you tried: `dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef`

Comment: Yes, I did. Temporarily I create a manifest tool inside of my project and installed dotnet-ef in order to use the tool, but globally, I can install it but, I can't run the command. Inside the project, with tool manifest, the command runs normaly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I tried the same commandes and the solution was to redelete everything and reinstall it then don't forget the :

> export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.dotnet" export
> PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.dotnet/tools/"

that  solved the problem for me !

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).